# Remaining limits error

Tags: python, tweepy

I am trying to find a way, to create a remain limits in tweepy, in order to handle remaining limits error that twitter API sends. I am using the following code:

```
limits = myapi.rate_limit_status()
remain_search_limits = limits['resources']['search']['/search/tweets']['remaining']
print remain_search_limits
print limits
```

Actually the above code prints:

```
179
{u'rate_limit_context': {u'access_token': u'179927437-vtHojLnksgUD3FfnueTWVag62Kx5mvAA3uhX7qd7'}, u'resources': {u'account': {u'/account/verify_credentials': {u'reset': 1399886205, u'limit': 15, u'remaining': 0}, u'/account/settings': {u'reset': 1399886857, u'limit': 15, u'remaining': 15}}, u'blocks': {u'/blocks/list': {u'reset': 1399886857, u'limit': 15, u'remaining': 15}, u'/blocks/ids': {u'reset': 1399886857, u'limit': 15, u'remaining': 15}}, u'users': {u'/users/contributors': {u'reset': 1399886857, u'limit': 15, u'remaining': 15}, u'/users/lookup': {u'reset':
```

The weird issue, is that every time that I print remain_search_limits I am getting 179 as answer. What should I have to use in order to waint until I ll be able again to fetched data from twitter?

My final code is the following:

```
limits = api.rate_limit_status()
remain_follower_limits = limits['resources']['followers']['/followers/ids']  ['remaining']

with open("ids.txt") as f:
    content = f.readlines()

ids = []
for page in tweepy.Cursor(api.followers_ids, user_id="dankanter").pages():
while remain_follower_limits >4:
    limits = api.rate_limit_status()
    remain_follower_limits = limits['resources']['followers']['/followers/ids']['remaining']
    ids.extend(page)
else:
    time.sleep(60)

print ids
print len(ids)
```

However sometimes it stucks in the line limits = api.rate_limit_status() inside while loop. In case that a user has millions of users it returns only a subset which actually is very small.

Comment: I get the same value, too ... unless/until I make a call to myapi.search, after which a lower value is returned. You may find some useful information in this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23653432/return-the-number-of-remaining-hits-tweepy

Comment: Since the `remain_search_limits` represents the _remaining_ search calls you can make, you can continue making additional search calls as long as this number is greater than zero.

Comment: I am trying to get user followers, hwat do I have to change in order to get the real limits for this case?

Comment: `limits['resources']` contains a dictionary for different API calls: `['account', 'blocks', 'users', 'friends', 'help', 'saved_searches', 'lists', 'search', 'application', 'trends', 'followers', 'favorites', 'friendships', 'geo', 'direct_messages', 'statuses', 'mutes']`.
`limits['resources']['followers']` contains entries for `'/followers/ids'` and `'/followers/list'`, each of which contain dictionaries with keys `'limit'`, `'remaining'` and `'reset'`.

Comment: Post it as an answer to get an upvote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*[Summarizing, clarifying and elaborating on the comment thread in the initial post]*

I get the same value, too ... unless/until I make a call to `myapi.search`, after which a lower value is returned.

`limits['resources']` contains a list of dictionaries for different resource families (types of API calls):

`['account', 'blocks', 'users', 'friends', 'help', 'saved_searches', 'lists', 'search', 'application', 'trends', 'followers', 'favorites', 'friendships', 'geo', 'direct_messages', 'statuses', 'mutes']`.

Each of the dictionaries associated with a resource family includes one or more keys representing the specific methods associated with that family. The values of each of those keys, in turn, are dictionaries with keys for `'limit'`, `'remaining'` and `'reset'`.

The documentation for [application/rate_limit_status](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/application/rate_limit_status) method describes these as follows:

> This method responds with a map of methods belonging to the families
>   specified by the resources parameter, the current remaining uses for
>   each of those resources within the current rate limiting window, and
>   its expiration time in epoch time. It also includes a
>   rate_limit_context field that indicates the current access token or
>   application-only authentication context.

Since `limits['resources']['search']['/search/tweets']['remaining']` represents the *remaining* search calls you can make, you can continue making additional `search` calls as long as this number is greater than zero; when it reaches zero, you will need to wait to make additional calls until the `reset` time (in [Epoch format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)) is reached.

With respect to a followup comment, the `limits['resources']['followers']` resource family contains keys for the methods `'/followers/ids'` and `'/followers/list'`, and the `'remaining'` calls can be accessed using the same pattern as for `search`.

You may find some additional useful information in this thread: [Return the number of remaining hits tweepy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23653432/return-the-number-of-remaining-hits-tweepy)