# Return the number of remaining hits tweepy

Tags: python, tweepy

EDIT: I am trying the following code in order to read a list of ids and get their corresponant names. I am trying to use  reamin_search_limits in order to avoid rate_limit errors.

```
limits = api.rate_limit_status()
remain_search_limits = limits['resources']['search']['/search/tweets']['remaining']
stream = open('myfile','w')
ss     = open('userNames', 'w')
for ids in content:
try:
    limits = api.rate_limit_status()
    remain_search_limits = limits['resources']['search']['/search/tweets']['remaining']
    print 'you have', remain_search_limits, 'API calls remaining until next hour'
    if remain_search_limits < 2:
         dtcode = datetime.utcnow()
         unixtime = calendar.timegm(dtcode.utctimetuple())
         sleeptime = rate_limit_json.get('reset_time_in_seconds') - unixtime + 10
         print 'waiting ', sleeptime, 'seconds'
         sleep(sleeptime)
    else:
         user = api.get_user(ids) 
         stream.write(str(user.id)+"\n")
         ss.write(str(user.name)+"\n")
except (tweepy.TweepError) as e:
    print e 
    stream.close()
    ss.close()
```

Everytime remain_search_limits is printed it return 180 until to get tweepError exception.

Comment: using "get" defaults to None if your key does not exist . Have you tried printing rate_limit_json to see if the key is there or if you are accessing it incorrectly?

Comment: {u'rate_limit_context': {u'access_token': u'accesstoke-...'}, u'resources': {u'account': {u'/account/verify_credentials': {u'reset': 1400068384, u'limit': 15, u'remaining': 15}, u'/account/settings': {u'reset': 1400068384, u'limit': 15, u'remaining': 15}}, u'blocks': {u'/blocks/list': {u'reset': 1400068384, u'limit': 15, u'remaining': 15}, u'/blocks/ids': {u'reset': 1400068384, u'limit': 15, u'remaining': 15}},...

Comment: Did you try 'remaining' instead of 'remaining_hits'?

Comment: Yes and I got the same result.

Comment: what is the api url you are using to get the info?

Comment: You 'remaining' key is nested under rate_limit_context key. Try ['/account/settings']['remaining']. The remaining hits varies by context. So, you need to know your context.

Comment: Padraic what exactly do you mean with api url.  Guru I tried remaining_hits = rate_limit_json['/account/settings']['remaining'] and I got    remaining_hits = rate_limit_json['account/settings']['remaining']
KeyError: 'account/settings'

Comment: I am looking at the docs for "GET application/rate_limit_status" and I don't see any key "remaining_hits" . Which remaining balance are you trying to access exactly?

Comment: Initial I tried just "remaining" but I got as an answer None.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example shows you how to access how many tweets are remaining.

```
print rate_limit_json["resources"]["search"]['/search/tweets']['remaining']
180

"resources" is the key you should be using to access the information inside.
```

If you want to update the value, put it in a loop reassigning the value after your time.sleep().

Put all the code inside a while loop: 
Something like this:

```
limits = api.rate_limit_status()
remain_search_limits = limits['resources']['search']['/search/tweets']['remaining']
while remain_search_limits >2:
  limits = api.rate_limit_status()
  remain_search_limits = limits['resources']['search']['/search/tweets']['remaining']
else:
   dtcode = datetime.utcnow()
   unixtime = calendar.timegm(dtcode.utctimetuple())
   sleeptime = rate_limit_json.get('reset_time_in_seconds') - unixtime + 10
   print 'waiting ', sleeptime, 'seconds'
   sleep(sleeptime)
```

I have not tested the code but it should be close to what you need.

You may want to sleep between calls, I am unfamiliar with the api so not sure exactly what you are doing.

Comment: print rate_limit_json["resources"]["search"]['/search/tweets']['remaining'] this statement returns me everytime 180.

Comment: you need to update the value after you make each call to the api get method. If you assign it to the variable once it will stay that value always.

Comment: I am actually trying to user = api.get_user(ids) stream.write(str(user.id)+"\n")
Is this the right key?limits['resources']['search']['/search/tweets']['remaining']

Comment: what remaining value are you trying to get, there are many different remaining values returned?

Comment: Actually I want given a list of user id's to get users names. So I am trying to figure which is the right remaining value that I should use.

Comment: I think you should edit your question including what the input is, "content" for example  and the exact output you want to get.